# Vector Union function performance in QGIS and ArcGIS DEsktop

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, performance, union

I am trying to find the union of two vector layers (both spatial indexed) - one land use polygons and another grid. In QGIS it is running since 4 days ago, but in ArcGIS Desktop it took less than 10 min.

Does anyone know if ArcGIS Desktop pre-processes vector(s) before actual union function?

The time difference cannot be this drastic!

Comment: I dont know why but Intersect, Union, Dissolve etc. are always alot faster in ArcGIS than QGIS for me.

Comment: which version of qgis do you use?

Comment: Most likely QGIS isn't running but crashed?

Comment: Are you using the Vector Overlay union tool?  Are the layers in the same projection?  I would perhaps do the following: 1. Run the Check Validity tool, 2. Redo the spatial indexes, and 3. use the GRASS v.overlay tool.  Whenever I run an overlay in either ArcGIS or QGIS I like being able to set a tolerance even if small on larger datasets and I don't see an option to that in the Vector Overlay tools.

Comment: Your question is interesting and can open a good discussion but , please, give some more information to people to understand your problem: which version of the software are you using? How big are your layers. I normally use both software and I have never had similar problems .